# Why aren't my indexes only being used in this Mongo Query?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongodb-.net-driver

I have what I thought was a pretty simple, straightforward query in Mongo, and have created the index:

```
{ "Ended" : 1, "EndDate" -1 }
```

However, when I run a simple query on it, it seems to recognize the index, but it's still scanning a LOT of objects to retrieve the data.  Here's my query and explain results:

```
PRIMARY> db.listing.find({ "Ended" : { "$ne" : true }, "EndDate" : { "$lte" : ISODate("2011-11-18T00:47:40.638Z") } }).explain();
{
        "cursor" : "BtreeCursor Ended_1_EndDate_-1 multi",
        "nscanned" : 24508585,
        "nscannedObjects" : 24508583,
        "n" : 24508583,
        "millis" : 108323,
        "nYields" : 0,
        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
        "isMultiKey" : false,
        "indexOnly" : false,
        "indexBounds" : {
                "Ended" : [
                        [
                                {
                                        "$minElement" : 1
                                },
                                true
                        ],
                        [
                                true,
                                {
                                        "$maxElement" : 1
                                }
                        ]
                ],
                "EndDate" : [
                        [
                                ISODate("2011-11-18T00:47:40.638Z"),
                                true
                        ]
                ]
        }
}
```

Any obvious ideas what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you replace `"Ended" : { "$ne" : true }` with `"Ended" : false`? (or doesn't that work in your schema?)

Answer (score 4):

Indexes aren't very good with $ne or $nin queries.You would be better off with

```
db.listing.find({ "Ended" : false , "EndDate" : { "$lte" : ISODate("2011-11-18T00:47:40.638Z") } })
```

The difference here though is that you would no longer obtain documents without an "Ended" field, or if the "Ended" Field is null or some other type.

[Indexing Advice & FAQ - MongDOB](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexing+Advice+and+FAQ#IndexingAdviceandFAQ-5.MongoDB%27s%24neor%24ninoperator%27saren%27tefficientwithindexes)

Answer (score 2):

The `n` field indicates that your query is matching 24.5M documents, the same number as `nscannedObjects`, which is normal behavior. If you don't need all 24.5M matched documents, you should add additional criteria to your query.

I also see that you're using `EndedDate: {$ne: true}`. While this will work, it will be slower than `EndedDate: false`, so if that field is only possibly `true` or `false`, you'd be better off going with the latter.

Comment: At this point I can't be sure ended exists. Maybe I should run a one time query to add this field to older documents

Comment: Yes, you should. The `$ne` operation is evil, because it implies a `$exists`, which can't be indexed.

Comment: What do you mean `$ne` implies `$exists`?

Comment: Never mind, I was expecting you could achieve `$exists` using a `$ne null` query, but that is nonsense. Still, I think we agree that `$ne` is evil and most probably the cause of the bad performance here.

Comment: There are useful cases for it. It doesn't perform as well as an exact match lookup, of course, but I wouldn't call it evil.

Answer (score 0):

It wont use index only because you'll be retrieving other fields via that query that aren't indexed.

Do all your documents have an EndDate in the past? As you're using LTE with the current date, it will still scan all index items previous to the current date. It's only scanning the index which is quicker than scanning the full document.

If you queried for a date range you'd see the number of scanned objects go down.

Comment: Most are in the past. Some are in the future.